# how to retrieve UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName with fileURLRef

Tags: ios, uialertview, core-audio, uilocalnotification, nsurl

I want to play a UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName from

```
alert.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

with :

```
 NSURL *soundFileURLRef  =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"wav"]];
 OSStatus  oStatus = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundFileURLRef, &aSoundID);
if (oStatus == kAudioServicesNoError)
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (aSoundID);
```

Is there a way I can get the name and the type of a `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System sounds are not available you your app, unfortunately. From the docs:

Note: System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface sound effects are not available to your iOS application. For example, using the kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert constant as a parameter to the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound function will not play anything.

Update

While Apple does say you can't access system sounds, I suppose they must mean that you can't access them for your own purposes, but I see that UILocalNotification.h provides:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

"Identifies the default system sound to play when a notification alert is displayed. You assign this value to the soundName property." I am now using this in my app and it seems to work fine.